# Escaping function wiping all data from text fields/areas

Tags: php, sql-server, escaping

I am attempting to replace ' with '' for error reasons within MSSQL queries. I understand that it could be more secure, I am just learning and they will get more secure.

So I used str_replace. and did this.

```
$dbTABLE = "Table_Name";
$query_sql = sprintf("UPDATE %s SET PageHTML = ('%s') WHERE PageID = '%d'",
$dbTABLE,
str_replace("'","''",$PageHTML),
$PageID);
```

Worked fine, but for consistency and ease of use I want to write a function I could just include in all pages. Function looks like this:

```
 function SQLencode($svalue) {

str_replace("'","''",$svalue);

}
```

and implemented like this:

```
SQLencode($PageHTML),
```

However this just wipes all data from the query, I don't understand why. All my data is just blank afterwards. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `return` the value from the function `SQLencode(..)`.

```
function SQLencode($svalue) {
    return str_replace("'","''",$svalue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to do the escaping yourself (sprintf is a bad choice), better use the [mssql_bind](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-bind.php) function to bind parameters to to the query.